# Response is different in Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, web-services, wsdl

I was working on retrieving response from the web service the problem is i am getting the response in SOAP format(for android) whereas for iPhone people they got the response in xml format...Is there anything wrong with me or not???

Whats the reason why different response formats?

Thanks

Comment: Already checked the headers of the request?

Comment: can you also post your URL? Don't you think you need to put some more explanations(code)?

Comment: @vstrien i didnt get u..

Comment: It's well possible that with different headers to the same URL, the server responds with different messages. One example is "UserAgent" (as Tim Messerschmidt already mentioned), another could be the content-type of the request.

Comment: I tell you this is the SOAP service handle that way..I can't understand why you are going as it is XML..It's not xml

Answer (score 0):

Do you add an UserAgent in the HTTPHeader?

Comment: no i didnt use...i got the response which is in SOAP format...For iPhone people they got it in xml format..

Comment: Try override the useragent to be the same as iPhone, if that fixes it you know its because the user agent is different. You could also try hitting the url from inside your device's browser, see what happens.